# How to show modals using global state with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

My React app uses react-router-dom for navigation.
Within each of the different components for these routes there is the potential need to show some form of Error Modal component when something goes wrong.
Instead of needing to import the same Error Modal into every component that needs it, manage state within the parent and declare toggle functions, I would like to do this once outside of all other components and just show the generic Error Modal when needed.

I suspect I may need to use Context API but I haven't used it before.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@BogdanSoare/how-to-use-reacts-new-context-api-to-easily-manage-modals-2ae45c7def81) but I'm not sure how to implement this with my application that has multiple routes.

Ideally I would like to trigger the modal from my axios interceptor in my index.js and have the modal show on top of whatever page the user is on.

index.js:

```
    //imports...
    axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, err => {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
        // Set show state for error modal here
      }
    
      return Promise.reject(err); 
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js:

```
  import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
  // other imports...

  const App = () => {
    return (    
        <Router>
              <Routes>
                <Route path='/page1' element={<Page1 />}></Route>
                <Route path='/page2' element={<Page2 />}></Route>
              </Routes>
          </Router>     
      );
  };
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. What have you tried already on your own? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example If you are looking for where to start, yes, using a React context, or Redux or similar global state management is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve a similar problem to this using the context API. See below for a brief explanation:

Create your ModalProvider

```
export const ModalProvider = (props) => {
    const createModal = () => { // ...some modal init code here }
    return (
        <ModalContext.Provider value={{ createModal }}>
            <Modal/>
            {props.children}
        </ModalContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

You can then wrap your App in this provider and you should have access to the createModal function when accessing context. Hope this helps!